# HAproxy redirect all traffic of a subdirectory to a TileServer instance

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a docker container running a [TileServer GL](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tileserver-gl) instance, serving at http://192.168.123.11:8080

I have a HAProxy instance, serving at https://192.168.234.10:443, with following configuration file:

```
global
    daemon
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 info
defaults
    log global
    option httplog
    timeout client          300s
    timeout server          300s
    timeout connect         300s

frontend frontend1
    bind    192.168.234.10:80
    bind    192.168.234.10:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/cert.key.pem ca-file /home/user/haproxy/ca.cer
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
    mode http
    use_backend maps if { path_beg /maps }
    
...

backend maps     
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    server maps-srv 192.168.123.11:8080
```

What I would like to achieve, is that from web browser, if I navigate to https://192.168.234.10/maps, I can see the maps server, with no broken links (so for example, a reference to http://192.168.123.11:8080/styles/style.css should be rewritten to https://192.168.234.10:443/maps/styles/style.css, and so for favicon, images etc.)

Thanks in advance,
Massi